# Is there a linter check to confirm that a related file has been updated in the commit?

Tags: github, commit, linter

I once saw (can't remember where) a lint check in a file that looked something like:
"If this file is modified, I will complain if files /somehwere/a and /somehwere/b aren't modified in the same commit".

Do you know of any linter capable of handling something like this? Maybe not a linter but something that can be integrated to a github repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CI system set up for your repository, you can run a command like the following, which will exit nonzero if there's a problem commit, and zero if all commits are fine (with `$BASE` and `$HEAD` set appropriately):

```
git rev-list $BASE..$HEAD | \
    xargs -L1 sh -c 'lines=$(git show --name-only $0 | grep -e somewhere/a -e somewhere/b | wc -l); \
    test $lines -ne 1 || { echo "bad commit $0"; false; }'
```

Any suitable CI system can test this by running a shell script and failing if it exits nonzero.